# Provision Secrets from Azure Key Vault to Azure App Service as environment variables

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

I have:

- [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) with a Docker container running in it. Inside the Docker container, there is a Python FastAPI Web App.
- [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview) with some App specific secrets in it (e.g. Public API Client Secret for a side service to send requests to)

I'm trying to set secrets to the App.

There are several examples when an app directly reads the secrets from Key Vault (e.g. [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#update-the-code:%7E:text=Security.KeyVault.Secrets-,Update%20the%20code,-Find%20and%20open)), but I believe the provisioning should not be the responsibility of the App.
Probably, secrets should be set as environment variables with the CD pipeline (correct me if it's a bad idea). Otherwise, the App knows details about the infrastructure where it's running, which, I guess, is not the best practice.

Is there a proper way to provision Key Vault secrets to the App environment?

Comment: if I understood your question then you want access different secret of keyvault as per environments then i suggest create different keyvault for different environment and keep url of keyvalut in config file of each envirnoment.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Thank you for your reply.

My question is not about different stagings (e.g. Dev, Pre-prod, Prod), but about how to provision (push) secrets from Key Vault to the App environment (so the secrets are stored, let's say, as the environment variables in Linux).

And I wonder if it is possible to make it without App fetching these variables on the startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the app service*

[image]

*The azure key vaults supplies  a way to  store keys  & secrets outside of an application, Using access polices  we can allow the application to access the keys with in keyvault*

*To access the keyvault as a environment variables in the azure app service we have to setup the polices mentioned as below*

*In the app services* => *identity* => *click on status is* ***ON***

[image]

*Go to the keyvault and the polices settings click on add polices*
*And the access polices page set any permissions for keys and secrets*

*In the select principal page search for the app service name and select then the app service can access as a environment variables*

[image]

*After that we have to add specific secrets in the app service and copy its in secret identifier as below format*

```
@microsoft.keyvault(secretUri={secret url from the keyvault})
```

[image]

*After adding the secret it will look like as below*

[image]

*By following the above steps we can access the secrets as a environment variables*

Comment: Hi Komali,
Thank you for your answer.
The steps you provided solve the issue. Your answer is marked as a solution.